# Trying to deploy a GitHub page but having trouble with CSS and JS not showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

I have easily deployed the files, but all I get is the plain HTML - none of the CSS or JS is transferring over. The GH page is mcdanielj8.github.com/todolist

I've even tried changing the path to todolist/assets/css/...., but that hasn't worked either.

I wish I could just upload a static site to Heroku!

Answer (score 0):

Got it - the path is case sensitive, apparently. Assets/css/main.css , etc worked.